# receiving out of order udp packets in linux

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp, boost-asio, epoll

I observed unexpected out of order packets receive sequence in my linux c++ program. After I limited the number of receive sockets, it received packets in sequence again. In addition, I had also tested the problem with either boost::asio, or epoll explicitly, but they both yield the same result. On the other hand, the same program works fine under Window environment (with boost.asio).

I find that rather strange, I am aware udp protocol does not guarantee packet receive in sequence. However, there is only 1 switch between the broadcast sender and receiver. Hence, out of order is physically impossible I believe. Plus the same program work fine under Window OS (under the same network).

Let assume packet is guarantee arrive in order at transport layer. additional sequence number checking is not an option, changing protocol is not either.

Comment: So the basic idea here is to use a protocol that allows out or order delivery, then demand in-order delivery anyway?

Answer (score 6):

Even localhost to localhost communication can be delivered out of order, its all implementation dependent. Stacks are free to implement a LIFO queue somewhere with UDP since in-order delivery isn't required. Every OS can and will behave differently. If you must use UDP, you **MUST** anticipate OOO packets and handle them.